# LINQ child records null

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I used Entity Framework to create my database schema and generate my code.  I have a table called Employee that has child records in a DaysOff table.  DaysOff has a foreign key to Employee and there is a 1 to * association in my model.  I ran a LINQ query on the Employee table and expected that my Domain.Employee object would be populated with the DaysOff but the DaysOff are null.  When I drill down in the Object I see "employee.DaysOff.Count threw an exception of type System.ObjectDisposedException".  Am I wrong to think that the child records will be populated?  How would I do this?  Here is the method I call to get my Employee:

```
public static Domain.Employee SelectEmployee(int employeeId)
{
    using (var db = new EmployeeEntities())
    {

        Domain.Employee emp = (from e in db.Employees
                       where e.EmployeeId == employeeId
                       select e
                             ).FirstOrDefault();

        return emp;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
A combination of the accepted answer below and the comments (all up-voted) helped me to solve this (yay!):

```
public static Domain.Employee SelectEmployee(int employeeId)
{
    using (var db = new EmployeeEntities())
    {

        Domain.Employee emp = (from e in db.Employees.Include("DaysOff")
                       where e.EmployeeId == employeeId
                       select e).FirstOrDefault();

        return emp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes.  This is a basic tenet of LINQ called Lazy Loading / Deferred Execution.  You may find it helpful to read up on some of the (large amount of) documentation out there such as: http://www.rizalalmashoor.com/blog/linq-to-entities-deferred-execution-and-lazy-loading/

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Am I wrong to think that the child records will be populated?

I'm *guessing* that it could be that the `DaysOff` is populated lazily, but by that point `EmployeeEntities` has been disposed. You might want to try something like:

```
using (var db = new EmployeeEntities().Include("Employee.DaysOff"))
```

Also note that your code in the `using` statement would be simpler written as:

```
return db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId);
```

---

**Edit**

The code above is not correct. `Include` must be used on an `ObjectQuery<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` and can't be applied to an `ObjectContext`/`DbContext`. Correct usage is:

```
using (var db = new EmployeeEntities())
{
    return db.Employees.Include("DaysOff")
        .FirstOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId);
}
```

Comment: @CodingGorilla: I'm a bit confused. He did get `ObjectDisposedException` so surely that means lazy loading is enabled? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Jon, you are already at EF version 19 :) (enable "auto-eager-loading" for whole context instance...). Currently you can't apply `Include` to a context, but you must put the `Include` inside of individual queries: `return db.Employees.Include("DaysOff").FirstOrDefault...`, etc.

Comment: Chris, 'he' = 'she'. ;) 
Slauma, thanks for your comment. I up-voted you because you helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

here is post talks about the loading of child entity

[Using DbContext in EF 4.1 Part 6: Loading Related Entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx)

**Eagerly loading related entities**

```
 // Load all prents and related childs
    var princesses1 = context.Parent
                          .Include(p => p.childs)
                          .ToList();
```

**Explicitly loading related entities**

```
var parent = context.parent.Find(1);
    context.Entry(parent)
        .Collection(p => p.childs)
        .Load();
```